# Reading xmlNodeList into a Dataset using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, web-services

UPDATE:

I want to dynamically dump the XML returned into a dataset without having to write out the columns names. The data returned is in very simple format, name of column, the data, then close of the name of column. Like this:

```
<runsql>
    <cst_id>0005675667</cst_id>
    <ind_last_name>Abe</ind_last_name>
    <ind_first_name>Adam</ind_first_name>
    <cst_ixo_title_dn/>
    <cst_org_name_dn>Acme University</cst_org_name_dn>
    <cst_eml_address_dn>Adam@acmeu.edu</cst_eml_address_dn>
</runsql>
```

I've been using a standard format to access our web services and return specific fields. I'm needing to modify this to dump the whole XML feed into an internal Dataset in VB.NET. This web service is pre-defined in my Web References section. I am successful with below code, but can't figure out a way, after much Googling and testing, to dynamically load all the columns into a Dataset. Can I get help using this format below to load into a Dataset?

```
    Dim proxy As New myWS.netFORUMXMLWebServices
    Dim strInSQL As String
    Dim strOutXML2 As XmlDocument
    strOutXML2 = New XmlDocument
    Dim oNode2 As XmlNode
    Dim oResultsNode2 As XmlNode

    strInSQL = "SELECT cst_eml_address_dn FROM WebServicesTable"

    strOutXML2.LoadXml("<myResults></myResults>")
    oResultsNode2 = proxy.runsql(strInSQL)
    Dim xmlNewDoc As XmlDocument
    xmlNewDoc = New XmlDocument
    xmlNewDoc.LoadXml(oResultsNode2.OuterXml)
    strOutXML2.DocumentElement.AppendChild(strOutXML2.ImportNode(xmlNewDoc.DocumentElement, True))
    Dim oResultsNodeList2 As XmlNodeList
    oResultsNodeList2 = xmlNewDoc.SelectNodes("//runsql")

    For Each oNode2 In oResultsNodeList2

        returnedEmail = oNode2.SelectSingleNode("cst_eml_address_dn").InnerText

    Next
```

And in case you were wondering the "runsql" is the parameter at the end of our web services that our vendor gave us. (webservices.asmx?op=runsql)

Comment: can we see the structure you are messing with...it seems like you are chopping up and repacking the return from `proxy.runsql` which could imported to a DS pretty directly.

Comment: @Plutonix, sure. I edited post. Importing into DS directly is exactly want I want. The above code shows what I have been using that works to retrieve values. I don't know how to edit my working code to dump it into DS directly without having to specify column names, etc.

Comment: @Plutonix sorry, first time doing the bounty thing. I thought by marking your response as answered, that you would automatically receive bounty.

Comment: Thanks!  I did see that this was your first time which is why I mentioned it before it was too late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you just need to load the `XMLDocument` using `DataSet.ReadXML`.  Here is one way:

```vb
' build xmlDoc to stand in for [proxy.runsql] return
Dim xdoc As New XmlDocument

' xml literal for the data
Dim x = <Document>
            <Employee>
                <Name>Ziggy Foobar</Name>
                <HireDate>2/11/2010</HireDate>
            </Employee>

            <Elements>
                <Name>Helium</Name>
                <Symbol>He</Symbol>
            </Elements>

            <Employee>
                <Name>Zoey Foobaz</Name>
                <HireDate>2/11/2013</HireDate>
            </Employee>

            <runsql>
                <cst_id>0005675667</cst_id>
                <ind_last_name>Abe</ind_last_name>
                <ind_first_name>Adam</ind_first_name>
                <cst_ixo_title_dn/>
                <cst_org_name_dn>Acme University</cst_org_name_dn>
                <cst_eml_address_dn>Adam@acmeu.edu</cst_eml_address_dn>
            </runsql>
        </Document>

' load litersl to XmlDocument
xdoc.LoadXml(x.ToString)            

'***** xdoc is now a stand in for the return from [proxy.runsql]

Dim ds As New DataSet

' load xdoc to dataset via node reader
Using xnr As New XmlNodeReader(xdoc)
    ds.ReadXml(xnr)           ' this is what you want
End Using                     ' dispose of node reader

Dim n As Integer                             ' test/view DS result
' verify: 2 tables?
For Each t As DataTable In ds.Tables
    Console.WriteLine("Table: " & t.TableName)

    ' we know there are 2, just verifying
    Console.WriteLine("Column Names: {0}, {1}", t.Columns(0).ColumnName,
                      t.Columns(1).ColumnName)

    n = 1
    For Each r As DataRow In t.Rows
        ' demo there only 2 cols
        Console.WriteLine("[Item {0}]:  {1}, {2}", n.ToString,
                          r(0).ToString, r(1).ToString)
        n += 1
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()

Next
```

The end result is 3 tables in the DS, with the noncontiguous Employee data glued back together.  There is no need to specify table or column names, it parses them itself.  In your case, you could ignore any other tables in the `DataSet` other than "runsql".   I pasted your runsql block after the test code was written, so some of the "only 2 columns" comments are wrong.  Output:

```vb
Table: Employee
Column Names: Name, HireDate
[Item 1]:  Ziggy Foobar, 2/11/2010
[Item 2]:  Zoey Foobaz, 2/11/2013

Table: Elements
Column Names: Name, Symbol
[Item 1]:  Helium, He

Table: runsql
Column Names: cst_id, ind_last_name
[Item 1]:  0005675667, Abe
```

*Works on My Machine<sup>TM</sup>*

Comment: Awsome! Thanks! So, I only needed to add 2 lines of your code to my pre-existing code:

        Dim ds1 As New DataSet
        ds1.ReadXml(New XmlNodeReader(xmlNewDoc))

Comment: Slight fix to the answer - the NodeReader supports `IDispose`, so it should be disposed when done.  It was a little hard to tell if what you wanted was actually simple or if I was not understanding.  The code to rip the XML made it hard to know if there was data being added or removed beforehand.  Glad it worked for you!